# PHP: string for DateTime object sets the year to 0000

Tags: php, datetime

My php code is being sent the following value for a `DateTime` variable:

```
2013-09-30T22:15:00+0000
```

Because it is going through the web server, what my code really gets is:

```
2013-09-30T22:15:00 0000
```

When I initialize a DateTime variable with the value above I get:

```
0000-09-30T22:15:00+0000
```

I know the correct/easy thing to do is have the `datetime` string url encoded. But does anyone knows why the trailing `0000` gets applied to the year in the `DateTime` object. Thanks

**Update:** Below is some sample code. The `$dateString` variable would be a `$_POST['timeStart']`. The client is not properly url encoding the POST data and the web server url decodes the + to be a space.

```
$dateString = "2013-09-30T22:15:00 0000";
$date = new DateTime($dateString);
echo $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . "\n";
```

Comment: By your reckoning `"2013-09-30T22:15:00+0100".` should give `"0100-09-30T22:15:00+0100"`... is this the case?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to create DateTime object with exact variable values.

Comment: Mark- No, your example string is properly formatted for a DateTime object and should retain the correct timestamp. I know I have a corrupted format. I'm curious why most of the DateTime is correct, but the year gets the 0000 timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the field as `2013-09-30T22:15:00+0000` through a GET/POST request without being URL escaped, the `+` symbol likely will be decoded into a space. Thus the difficulty: fix the space and replace it with a `+` and the date will parse correctly.